# ActiveRecord call to PG stored procedure fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

```
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute
        ( "SELECT * FROM search_results(p_limit := 12,
         p_offset := 0,p_blocked_ids := '',p_following_ids 
        := '54,171,174',p_sort := 'latest',
        p_tags := '', p_search := '(O'neil)')" )
```

The special characters in the `p_search` param fail. I tried double quoting and `$$ $$` quoting with but it's not solving the issue.

What is the proper way to escape special characters in this query?

Full error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "neil"
LINE 1: ...t := 'latest',         p_tags := '', p_search := '(O'neil)')
                                                                ^
: SELECT * FROM search_results(p_limit := 12,          p_offset := 0,p_blocked_ids := '',p_following_ids          := '54,171,174',p_sort := 'latest',         p_tags := '', p_search := '(O'neil)')
    from /Users//.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'
    from /Users//.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `block in execute'
    from /Users//.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:590:in `block in log'
    from /Users//.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    from /Users//.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in `log'
    from /Users//.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:97:in `execu
```

The suggestion from the assumed duplicate has not helped in this case and returns `', p_search := ''o''neil'')`

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: syntax error pointing at the quote in the string

Comment: Can you post the full error message here? (or paste it on pastebin?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute
        ( "SELECT * FROM search_results(p_limit := 12,
         p_offset := 0,p_blocked_ids := '',p_following_ids 
        := '54,171,174',p_sort := 'latest',
        p_tags := '', p_search := '(O\'neil)')" )
```

Notice the extra `\` in `(O\'neil)'` near the end.

I think `'(O'neil)'` is being read by PostgreSQL and since there is an single quote after `(O`, the string ends there and it would complain about the syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately the backslash is not helping and the same syntax error is showing

Comment: Does `\\\'` instead of `\'` help? Because I think the first `\` would be escaped by Ruby itself.

Comment: doing a gsub("'", "\\'") seems to help.  Thank you !